# Add a user to parse role

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a new user and adding it to an already existing ParseRole, but i'm getting the **ParseException: object not found for update** after performing **await parseRole.SaveAsync();**.

I checked in the Parse website and both the Role and User are saved (the ids returned by c# code are correct), but the Role hasn't that user.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task CanCreateCustomer()
        {
            var customer = ParseObject.Create<ApplicationUser>();
            customer.FirstName = GetRandom.FirstName();
            customer.LastName = GetRandom.LastName();
            customer.Password = "123";
            customer.Username = customer.GetUserName();

            Assert.IsNull(customer.ObjectId);
            await customer.SignUpAsync();

            Assert.IsNotNull(customer.ObjectId);
            var parseRole = await ParseRole.Query.Where(x => x.Name == Roles.CustomerRole).FirstAsync();
            parseRole.Users.Add(customer);
            await parseRole.SaveAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I didn't set the ACL for my roles to allow write access to the logged user (or public, in case of my unit test)